# why subject negative verb <or> to infinitive

Tags: reported-speech

> 1.He asked me why I didn't run and fetch the doctor.
>
> 2.He asked me to run and fetch the doctor.

I wanted to know which sentence is more natural and formal for reprted speech.

Comment: What's the intended meaning? I have to ask because the two sentences don't mean exactly the same.

Comment: Same question here. OP appears to be confused. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/370955/why-not-or-to-infinitive-in-indirect-speech

Answer (score 1):

There's an accuracy concern here. Both are valid sentences, but would be used in different cases. Did he ask you for a doctor, or did he ask you why you had not gotten him a doctor already?

In most cases where someone requires medical attention

> He asked me to run and fetch the doctor

Sounds better.